# Create new list based on ordered elements of two lists

Tags: python, list

I have two lists and want to create a new based on each element of the list.

```
list1 = [23, 57, 223, 246, 286, 429]

list2 = [17, 138, 425, 680, 535, 1063]
```

and I want new list such as:

```
list3 = [23, 17, 57, 138, 223, 425]
```

which is

```
list3 = [list1[0], list2[0], list1[1], list2[1], ...]
```

How should I proceed. I know append doesn't work, neither does zip.

Comment: Does `list3` intentionally not contain all the elements of `list1` and `list2`?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `itertools.chain` to flatten the output of `zip`:

```
from itertools import chain

list3 = [*chain(*zip(list1, list2))]
```

Or plainer with a nested comprehension:

```
list3 = [x for pair in zip(list1, list2) for x in pair]
```

If you only need some part of the input lists, just use an appropriate slice:

```
list3 = [*chain(*zip(list1[:3], list2))]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use double `for` loop. One to iterate over the zipped tuple and one to iterate over the elements of the tuple:

```
x=[k for j in zip(list1,list2) for k in j]
```

Answer (score -1):

Trying for a one-liner is nice, but it does mean that whoever reads it (including you in a few months time) is going to have to sit there working through what it does.

It may be much more immediately readable to do it the slightly more verbose way:

```
out = []
for x in zip(list1, list2):
    out.extend(x)
```

Answer (score -2):

loop through the index of lists and add elements from both lists at once to result

```
list1 = [23, 57, 223, 246, 286, 429]
list2 = [17, 138, 425, 680, 535, 1063]
result = []
for i in range(0,len(list1)):
   result.append(list1[i])
   result.append(list2[i])
print(result)
```